# Loop all the panels in form C#

Tags: c#

Here's the logic to what I'm trying to do. First I will loop all the `panels` in my `form` and check if `visible` is equals to `true`, if yes then it will change the value to `false`. Basically All the Panels that are visible will be hidden.

The problem is when I run my program with the code below all of the controls disappeared.

My Approach:

```
foreach (var c in Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel));
        c.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: If `c` isn't true, that means it's false, so you can just set it to `false` to and get the same effect, though you probably want `c.Visible = !c.Visible`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make **visible --> invisible** and vice-versa, use this -

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
    {
        // Invert the visibility state of the panel
        c.Visible = !c.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that, please accept the answer if it worked for you!!

Comment: In which method do you need controls and why?

Comment: I will create a static method for that, because i will use it many times.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`OfType<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) to iterate over the Panels only:

```
foreach (Panel p in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    p.Visible = !p.Visible;
```

And if you're using [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), you can have an even shorter version:

```
Controls.OfType<Panel>().ForEach(p => p.Visible = !p.Visible);
```